# How to add latex in ggplot axis text?

Tags: r, ggplot2

### Goal

Put latex in x-axis text in `ggplot2`.

### Data

Following is my sample data:

```
df <- structure(list(LV_type = c("LV Type: Car", "LV Type: Car", "LV Type: Car"
), reac_to_stpd_scn = c("Moving LV", "Moving LV", "Moving LV"
), Variable = c("AIC_AV_W_base", "AIC_AV_H_base", "AIC_TI_base"
), AIC = c(95.9878231314661, NA, 97.0658161329315), var_symbols = c("$\\dot{\\theta_{W}}$", 
"$\\dot{\\theta_{H}}$", "$\\tau^{-1}$")), row.names = c(NA, -3L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

### Attempts

```
library(ggplot2)
library(latex2exp)
```

Following obviously does not work:

```
ggplot(df) +
  geom_point(aes(var_symbols, AIC, color = Variable))
```

I also tried following:

```
ggplot(df) +
  geom_point(aes(Variable, AIC, color = Variable)) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c("AIC_AV_W_base" = expression("$\\dot{\\theta_{W}}$"),
                              "AIC_AV_H_base"   = expression("$\\dot{\\theta_{H}}$"),
                              "AIC_TI_base" = expression("$\\tau^{-1}$")))
```

[image]

I also tried to replace `expression` with `latex2exp::TeX` above, but that also did not work. Please suggest how can I put latex in axis labels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have the expressions as a variable in your data frame, you can use them as the x aesthetic and pass the `TeX()` function to the label argument in `scale_x_discrete()`.

```
library(latex2exp)
library(ggplot2)

 ggplot(df) +
  geom_point(aes(var_symbols, AIC, color = Variable)) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = TeX)
```

[image]

You can do the same thing with the legend if needed using `scale_color_discrete()`.